# Creating a students' record database for a school

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a student database for a school. I have everything I need except for one thing...

-- When a school year and semester ends. Since the tables I currently have are for records of the current school year, I'm trying to find a way to permanently keep those records so that even after the student graduates, his/her information will still be stored in the DB.

Can anyone give me an idea of how I should build it? I just need to be able to visualize the structure of the database.

Comment: Wow, building an entire DBMS is quite a project. Good luck!

Comment: Add a date field to the appropriate tables?  And a DBMS is an entire DataBase Management System, like MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.  You're probably making a DB - there's a big difference.

Comment: Perhaps I named the topic wrong? Anyway, I just need the part where my system can permanently keep the records of its students.

Comment: @Nath: yes, it's like the difference between creating a spreadsheet application (like MS Excel) or a spreadsheet (like one Excel file).

Comment: There, I edited the title. Apologies :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data have to be in your OLTP-system, add an extra field in your table, indicating the school year:

- REF_SCHOOL_YEAR

Create a new table with all the school years:

- ID_SCHOOL_YEAR
- STARTING_YEAR
- ENDING_YEAR

Now your application can easily get the current year (where NOW() between STARTING_YEAR AND ENDING_YEAR) and query the table using that ID_SCHOOL_YEAR.

If the data don't need to be accessible via your application, just stored "for recordkeeping purposes", OLAP (a datawarehouse) might be a better solution.

Comment: Actually, the system requires that it can access those records for verification (ie to verify if the student is qualified to enroll on a subject with prerequisites)

Comment: Then put it in your OLTP. Add a field on which to differiate the year by, as I explained. Since your using MySQL (an RDBMS), a foreign key to a new table would be the way to go. My answer shows how :]

Comment: Thank you. That row was all I need.

Answer (score 1):

One tool that has helped me is for mysql but will help you visualize. It's called Mysql workbench. Also, try to learn about e-r diagrams and how to think-relational.

As for the specifics, I think Konerak is rigt.

[image]

Comment: My main concern is keeping the grades of the student's grades. The system will need to verify if the student is qualified to enroll to its requisite subject.

Answer (score 0):

Once I have developed a software for a school with following database structure, this may help someone.

```
TABLE [Students](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [SectionID] [int] ,
    [RollNo] [nvarchar](50) ,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [RegDate] [smalldatetime],
    [Status] [tinyint] ,
    [image] [varbinary](max) ,
    [BirthDate] [smalldatetime] ,   
    [Gender] [tinyint] ,   
    [LeavingDate] [smalldatetime] ,
    [registration_no] [varchar](50) ,       
    [LastSchoolName] [nvarchar](150) ,
    [FatherName] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [MotherName] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [Phone] [varchar](50) ,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) ,) 

TABLE [Classes](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) ,
    [isActive] [bit] )

TABLE [Sections](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) ,
    [ClassID] [int] ,
    [isActive] [bit] ) 

TABLE [FeeTypes](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [Amount] [int] ,
    [Fee Title] [varchar](50),
    [Status] [bit] )

TABLE [Payments](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [StudentID] [int] ,
    [Receivable] [decimal](18, 2) ,
    [Received] [decimal](18, 2) ,
    [Date] [smalldatetime] ,
    [FeeTypeID] [int] , 
    [Status] [tinyint] ,            
    [SortNumber] [int] 
)

TABLE [Invoices](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [IssueDate] [smalldatetime] ,
    [ValidDate] [smalldatetime] ,
    [DateFrom] [smalldatetime] ,
    [DateTo] [smalldatetime] ,
    [sDate] [smalldatetime] ,
    [DueDate] [smalldatetime] ,
    [Status] [bit] ,    
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) ) 

TABLE [FeeReceipts](
    [ID] [int]   ,
    [StudentID] [int] ,
    [Invoice No] [int] 
    [PaymentID] [int] )
```